# Razor - Convert model object to a json object in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to convert a model object to a json object.
I tried doing this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myobj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.MyObject))';
</script>
```

However the above `myobj`is string. I tried converting it to an object using this

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(myobj)
```

However the above gives a parsing error. 
My question is what is the fastest way to convert `Model.MyObject` to a json object.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myobj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MyObject));
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce simple model, it still worked.

Can you try to serialize all your model after that get MyObject property?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myobj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))';
    var json = JSON.parse(myobj);
    var myObject = json.MyObject;
</script>
```